# Onchange Request For Two Textfield

Tags: javascript, ajax, onchange

This is my first question here....i want to ask for help about AJAX Request...
This is my code :

```
    $("#grade").change(function() { 
    var grade = $("#grade").val(); 
    $.ajax({ type : "POST", 
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>convert/calcmutu", 
    data : "grade="+grade, 
    success: function(hm) { 
        $("#hm").val(hm); 
    } 
    success: function(am) { 
        $("#hm").val(am); 
    } 
    }); 
}); 

<input type="text" name="grade" id='grade'/> 
<input type="text" name="am" id='am'/>
<input type="text" name="hm" id='hm'/>
```

Now, how to make the request send to 2 textfield ? i have try to make it like this

```
$("#grade").change(function() {
          var grade   = $("#grade").val();
          $.ajax({
            type  : "POST",
            url   : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>convert/calcmutu",
            data  : "grade="+grade,
            success: function(hm) {
                $("#hm").val(hm);
            }
            success: function(am) {
                $("#hm").val(am);
            }
          });
       });
```

but nothing happened

Comment: which version of jquery are you using? can you also post the HTML?

Comment: i'm using jquery 1.7.1...yes i have edited my post...there are HTML code too